# How many different way to buy 10 platters for 10 people. The options for the plat ters are brisket, pulled pork, half chicken, or rack of ribs

Tags: permutations, combinations

> You're buying barbecue meat platters for 10 people. The options for the plat ters are brisket, pulled pork, half chicken, or rack of ribs. There are no sides. What kind of podunk BBQ place doesn't have sides? And still calls it a platter?

> (a) How many different ways are there to select 10 platters?

> (b) You've arrived late in the day, so there are only enough portions of brisket to make at most 4 platters. Now how many ways are there to select the 10 platters?

> (c) You've arrived even later in the day, so there are only enough portions left to make at most 3 brisket platters and 2 rack of rib platters. How many ways are there to select the 10 platters?

**My answer :**

(a) As there are 10 platters to buy and four types are available, therefore we can select the first platter in 4 ways and rest of th 9 also in 4 ways.

Therefore total of $4^{10}$ ways to buy.

(b) similarly at most 4 briskets are available at most. Therefore 4 platters can be chosen in 4 ways and rest of them can be chosen in 3 ways.

Therefore the total no of way = $4^4.3^6$

(c) Similarly in this case the ans is = $4^2.3^1.2^7$

Is my solution correct? And does the extra lines in the question is useful in terms of solution of the question?

Comment: Your first solution is correct.  In the second problem, notice that the ten people can order up to four brisket platters.  They do not have to order all four.

Comment: But there are only 4 no of briskets are available in the second problem. So four persons can buy in 4 ways and rest of the 6 persons have 3 choices each. So I don't get it where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As N. F. Taussig mentions, your solution to the first problem is correct.

For the second problem, you need to account for **the order**, i.e. when the brisket might be chosen for a platter. Your solution is the case where you also consider brisket as a fourth option for only the first four platters.

While not elegant, the following should work:

- In (b), you can first choose the number of platters with briskets $k \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$.
- Then you have $\binom{10}{k}$ possibilities for the $k$ of $10$ platters with briskets and for the remaining $10 - k$ platters $3$ options each.
- So the total number of ways to select the 10 platters is $\sum_{k = 0}^4 \binom{10}{k} \cdot 3^{10-k} = 966654$.

A similar, nested argument can be made for (c) with $\sum_{k = 0}^3 \sum_{l = 0}^2 \binom{10}{k} \cdot  \binom{10 - k}{l} \cdot 2^{10 - k-l} = 379904$.